# Animating gif in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

It's my first question here due to i tend to search more than ask but i haven't found answer to my question anywhere at the moment.

I'm making a simple duck hunt game for uniwersity, but i cannot find any way of making my ducks fly from bottom to the top of the screen. I managed to make one duck fly once but only when i was pressing button. Tried so many diffrent things that i got in my head but nothing worked.

Her is my code: http://pastebin.com/gMd8M7bZ

I know that i should have my ducks in array but atm i just tried another solution and it didnt worked to. Hope you can help me guys(i'm newb in JS:/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can use the [libgif](https://github.com/buzzfeed/libgif-js) library.**

It allows you to start/stop the gif and control which frame the gif is on.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./libgif.js"></script>
<img src="./example1_preview.gif" rel:animated_src="./example1.gif"
 width="360" height="360" rel:auto_play="1" rel:rubbable="1" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $$('img').each(function (img_tag) {
        if (/.*\.gif/.test(img_tag.src)) {
            var rub = new SuperGif({ gif: img_tag } );
            rub.load(function(){
                console.log('oh hey, now the gif is loaded');
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I can't see how this is going to help me :/ Shall i use it for redrawing my gif? Couse i'm using it kinda like image. It has let's say bottom position:0. After 0.5 sec i want it to be 10 then 20 and so on. With one duck i managed to do this on button press but when i wanted to put them into array and loop it it didn't worked.

Comment: See these links hope it will help you.. https://github.com/antimatter15/jsgif and http://antimatter15.com/wp/2010/07/javascript-to-animated-gif/